# Directive not init properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I Use the angular-ui-bootsrap tabs directive to create the tabs. But when I console.log on each controller and link function, the initialize order is not correct.

**I Expect**

```
outer - controller
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
outer -  Link
```

**The Result**

```
outer - controller
outer -  Link
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
Inner -  Controller
Inner -  Link
```

As you can see the outer directive have init the link with the controller at the same time, not linking after the inner directive has been initialize.

Go to the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w915x0BZGmg0R9J8S719?p=preview) and check the console.

Answer (score 1):

Put your link-function in $timeout service. See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJ1DszfuM0FSHf20Ik4O)

```js
// UPD: Add $timeout service
.directive('uibTabset', function($timeout) {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      active: '=?',
      type: '@'
    },
    controller: 'UibTabsetController',
    controllerAs: 'tabset',
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
      return attrs.templateUrl || 'uib/template/tabs/tabset.html';
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // UPD: put link-function in $timeout
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log("outer -  Link");
        
        scope.vertical = angular.isDefined(attrs.vertical) ?
          scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.vertical) : false;
        scope.justified = angular.isDefined(attrs.justified) ?
          scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.justified) : false;
        if (angular.isUndefined(attrs.active)) {
          scope.active = 0;
        }
      });
      // END UPD
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: The timeout would work, but is there a way cleaner than timeout? And why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It is the ng-repeat that is causing this issue. However I am going to ask another question about this problem.